# Text.IsEmpty Opposite

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have this CheckBox

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="CheckItem"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Faccette, Path=Text.isEmpty, Mode=OneWay}"
                     />
```

Faccette is a TextBlock, i  need the opposite of the Text.isEmpty.
Is it possible without a Converter?

Comment: You either need a converter or another property called `IsNotEmpty` - though to do that, you'd have to bind to something other than the control.

Comment: IsNotEmpty does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a Style with DataTriggers:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Faccette, Path=Text}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Faccette, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```